# Cognos Job to send one email with all reports

Tags: jobs, cognos-11

In the older versions of Cognos we had Events which run multiple reports and at the end it can send 1 email with all the reports attached in one email. This is good when sending a report packet to users with different but related reports in one email.
We use Cognos 11.1.7 and it still has Events but IBM is pushing to start using Jobs. The problem is in Jobs you can add multiple reports but each report will be sent out as its own email. Is there a way for Cognos Job to run all the reports and attached the output in 1 single email.

I tried creating a job to run 4 reports and setting the job options to send the email, but it still sent 4 separate emails. I am expecting 1 email with 4 attachments.